# Include doesn't work, getting strange path: (/usr/local/php53/lib/php) - Whats wrong? (WPAlchemy)

Tags: metabox, include, wpalchemy

I´m using WPAlchemy which is a helper class for metabox creation. I´m trying to include it through my functions.php but I´m getting strange errors when I have WP_Debug set to true.

For some reason Wordpress is including a lot of stuff in the url that it shouldn't, this is the warning I get.

```
Warning: include_once(/customers/d/d/4/mydomain.com/httpd.www/nysida/wp-content/themes/aaa/WPAlchemy/MetaBox.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /customers/d/d/4/mydomain.com/httpd.www/nysida/wp-content/themes/aaa/functions.php on line 58 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening ‘/customers/d/d/4/mydomain.com/httpd.www/nysida/wp-content/themes/aaa/WPAlchemy/MetaBox.php’ for inclusion (include_path=’.:/usr/share/php’) in /customers/d/d/4/mydomain.com/httpd.www/nysida/wp-content/themes/aaa/functions.php on line 58 Notice: Use of undefined constant   – assumed ‘ ’ in /customers/d/d/4/mydomain.com/httpd.www/nysida/wp-content/themes/aaa/header.php on line 53
```

What´s up with the strange url?

Comment: Can you post your include code as well?  And maybe some background on your WP install?

Comment: and can you maybe break that `Warning:` code up onto multiple lines to make it easier to read?

Comment: that URL isn't a URL, it's the server path

Answer (score 1):

When I've used WPAlchemy, the instructions have me put the WPAlchemy directory directly into the `wp-content` folder - not the theme folder.  It looks like your include code points to your theme directory.  All the other stuff in the path is specific to your host, and probably not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I trialed-and-errored my way to a solution that worked. Still don´t know exactly why this error occured, I did have the WPAlchemy class in the wp-content folder. Anyway it seems to work now and I´m not getting any errors.

Thanks for answering.